# Using .htaccess in Wordpress to rewrite category to a static url

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been looking for hours trying to find a solution that actually fits with my desire, and I can't make it work. What I want is, using WordPress, to have a /blog/ URL which actually shows the content of /category/blog/. I know that this can be done by creating a custom template for a page called "blog" and adding a loop to show the content of "category", but I don't want that. I want to show at /blog/ the contents of /category/blog, so /category/blog/page/2 can be accessed from /blog/page/2...

How can this be achieved with .htaccess? I've been trying tons of different options and it's just redirecting "blog" or "blog/" to the category page. This is the rule I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^(blog)/?$ /category/blog [L]
```

Thanks for your time and best regards.

Comment: Use `RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ /category/blog$1 [L]`

Comment: You are wasting your time with .htaccess, even if the RewriteRule is fine, WordPress will redirect to the URL it sees is corrent, @slapyo got it right, use WordPress SEO.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I've tried that, but if I enter in "/blog" I get a 404, and if I get in "/blog/" I get redirected to "/category/blog". What I want is to show the content with that URL, not redirection, something like a virtual host with Apache. Thanks.